# How to do Custom Sorting in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I want to do custom sort by `Customercode` for `tblCustomer` table.

`CustomerCode` consist of `(3 char of Surname) + 1 + (PostCode)`

Here, 1 will increment if Same Surname and postcode customer found.

For e.g. `ABB12615`, `ABB22615`

So mainly I want to sort this by

```
First 3 Letters of Surname + Index + PostCode.
```

I tried to do in this manner :

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(customerCode, 1, 3), customerCode)
```

but it gives me output like this:

```
ABB12615
ABB12715
...
...
...
..
.
ABB22615
```

But I want output in this order:

```
 ABB12615 

 ABB22615

 ABB12715
```

and so on

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes it is possible, did you try anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your expected results you *really* want to sort on

```
Surname, postcode, index
```

which would be

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(customerCode, 1, 3), 
         SUBSTRING(customerCode, 5, 4), 
         SUBSTRING(customerCode, 4, 1)
```

Comment: but the last time I looked a postal code was (02816) my town or 5 digits.  My solution uses len() to take the rest of the string.  Tested with data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COlumn1 = 'ABB12615' THEN 1
              WHEN COlumn1 = 'ABB22615' THEN 2
              WHEN COlumn1 = 'ABB12715' THEN 3
              END
```

Comment: Sorry this is not possible, because I just gave example but there are thousands of thousand customers are there.

Comment: @HakooDesai So you are trying to sort based on last for digits?

Comment: No I am trying to sort based on (First 3 Digits of Surname)+ Index (like 1,2,3,4,5,6..etc) + Postcode. Please Have look to my post.

Answer (score 0):

This code should sort the way you want.

```
-- play table
create table #postal
(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  code varchar(16)
)
go

-- remove data
truncate table #postal;
go

-- add data
insert into #postal
values
('ABB12615'),
('ABB22615'),
('ABB12715'),
('AAA29615'),
('AAA19615');
go

-- sort
select 
  * 
from 
  #postal
order by 
  substring(code, 1, 3), 
  substring(code, 5, len(code) - 5),
  substring(code, 4, 1)
```

Output from the test run.

[image]

Comment: I expect o/p ids in this order: 5,4,1,2 and then 3

Comment: Might have put the first image in that I took that did not have your order correct.  Will update later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.
Assuming that your CustomerCode format will remain the same, you can use the below code.
You need to split the Customercode based on String functions & before sorting index, need to convert them to integer as shown below:

```
select * from tblCustomer  
ORDER BY
SUBSTRING(Customercode , 1, 3) --SurName 
,CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Customercode , 4, 1)) --Index
,CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Customercode , 5, 5)) --Post Code; You can optionally remove the convert to int function if your post code will contain characters
```